# node.jsを使用したチャットに別の端末から接続できない

Tags: node.js

node.jsでsocket.ioを使ったチャットです。ローカルからは接続可能で、チャットの画面も正しく表示され、メッセージの投稿も行えます。ローカルからのアクセスは`http://192.168.10.5:3000`/(ポート番号3000)のように接続させています。上記のアドレスでチャット用のhtmlも読み込んでくれます。

同じように同じLAN内の別の端末から、上記のアドレスに接続を試みるのですが、エラーとなってしまいます。その別の端末には、node.jsやsocket.ioはインストールされていませんし、チャット用のhtmlファイルも保存していません。やはり、ローカルPC以外からのアクセスの場合、何らかの対策が必要なのでしょうか。

Comment: エラーの内容と、動作環境（OS などにより、状況を調査するために使えるコマンドが異なるため）を質問に追記すると、回答が得られ易いです。

Comment: 十中八九はファイアーウォールの設定かなぁと思われます。

Comment: おそらくサーバ側を起動するときに使っているbinding addressが原因かもしれません。 socket.ioでサーバを起動するコードで `server.listen(8080, 'localhost');` などになっていませんか？サーバ側は接続を待ち受けるポートと、その範囲を指定します。このことをbinding addressと呼ぶのですが、この例ではlocalhostになっているため、localhost以外からは接続が通らなくなります。この場合は `192.168.10.0` や `0.0.0.0` のような設定をすると、通るのですが、現状ではこの答えで良いのかもよくわからないので、良ければどのようなサーバサイドを作ったのか、コードなどを出していただけないでしょうか。